# Realm: Do we need to write each and every new RLMObject we create

Tags: cocoa, realm

Started using Realm as storage layer for my app.   This is these scenario I am trying to solve

Scenario:  I get a whole bunch of data from the server.  I convert each piece of data into a RLMObject.  I want to just "save" to persistent storage at the end.  In between, I want these RLMObjects create dot reflected when I do a query

I don't see a solution for this in `Realm`.  Looks like only way to is to write each Object back into the Realm DB after they are created.  Documentation also says that writes are expensive.  Is there any way around?

To reduce the overhead, I guess I could maintain list of objects created and write all of them in one transaction.  Still seems like a lot of work.  Is that how it is intended to be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the objects as standalone without adding them to the Realm, and then add them all in single transaction (which is very efficient) at the end.

Check out the documentation about creating objects here: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#creating-objects

There is also an example of adding objects in bulk here, where they get added in chunks so that other threads can observe the changes as they happens: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand the difference between following two statements 1. Your statement above of "crete objects as standalone and add them in a single transaction"  2. Statement in sample "Sharing Realm instances across threads is not supported".  I am creating an instance of a class that is a sub-class of RLMObject to store my data.  Does statement 2 mean that I can't start a dispath_async to create a background thread that writes these objects to Realm?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You just need to create a new `RLMRealm` instance to write on other thread.

Comment: Standalone objects can be shared across threads. It is only objects that have been added to a Realm that cannot be shared (since the Realm could be in a different state in the other thread).